# ML.NET LoadFromEnumerable with complex object

Tags: c#, ml.net

I want to create a `IDataView` from complex objects.

Let say my objects will be these simple classes:

```cs
class Foo
{
    public Bar bar { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

(Of course, in my code there are more fields in `Foo`, and some of them are objects or collections).

Now I trying to load a collections of `Foo`s with [`DataOperationsCatalog.LoadFromEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.dataoperationscatalog.loadfromenumerable?view=ml-dotnet):

```cs
var mlContext = new MLContext();
var foos = new List<Foo>
{
    new Foo
    {
        bar = new Bar {num = 5}
    }, 
    new Foo
    {
        bar = new Bar {num = 5}
    }
}.AsEnumerable();
var dataview = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(foos);
```

And I getting the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : Could not determine an IDataView type for member **bar**
>   Parameter name: rawType

Even I register the **`Bar`** object as [`DataViewType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.dataviewtype?view=ml-dotnet), nothing get better:

```cs
DataViewTypeManager.Register(NumberDataViewType.Int32, typeof(Bar));
```

Comment: How do you expect ML.NET to "magically" convert an object of type Bar to an int without providing any additional information? If i were you i would flatten out your object graph to something more on a "record" format

Comment: @jakobandersen I'm just now flattening my object structure :-). I would expect from `ml.net` to do the same. Use a column named `bar_num` or something like. This will surely be a unique name when the column name will be in the order of the fields we have passed. The only problem is recursion in object references.

Comment: @baruchiro You may want to change the method name "LoadFromEnumerate" in the title to "LoadFromEnumerable," it might make the thread easier to find. I've run into the same problem & have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Same Problem :/ Any solution here?

Comment: @KevinV don't know, I asked it years ago